# PHP MySQLi get columns from foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables:

```
'auktionen'

id|uid|typ(FK)|min|max|menge|...


'typen'

id|typ
1|Hack
2|Schredder
```

where `typ` in `typen` is just a textutal representation, which I would like to get.

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT anzeigentyp, typ, holzart,
qualitaet, rinde, min, max, menge FROM auktionen WHERE uid = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($anzeigentyp, $typ, $holzart, $qualitaet, $rinde, $min, $max, $menge);
$stmt->store_result();
```

So when fetching all my results I want to get "Hack" instead of the referencing id (in case it is 1). I guess it needs some JOIN to be achieved and I tried it like this without success:

```
$prep_stmt = "SELECT anzeigentyp, typen.typ, holzart,
qualitaet, rinde, min, max, menge FROM auktionen WHERE uid = ? 
JOIN typen ON auktionen.typ = typen.typ";
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Just copy, paste error, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move the where clause to the end and join the corresponding columns `typen.id` and `auktionen.typ`

```
select a.anzeigentyp, t.typ, a.holzart, a.qualitaet, a.rinde, a.`min`, a.`max`, a.menge
from auktionen a
join typen t on t.id = a.typ
where ...
```

Comment: What do I have to SELECT to get the join result? I can see it is added as a column at the end when using SELECT *. The column is named typ as well, so there are two columns with the same name resulting in an unambigous error when trying to SELECT typ